# Which character has the most deaths to his/her name?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

In the Dragon Ball series, we see tons of people dying and being revived by the dragon balls.
This triggered my curiosity to know which character has the most deaths to his/her name in the whole Dragon Ball series. Who is it, and how many times did he/she die?

Comment: is it even necessary to ask? its Krillin little bald dude always gets it lol his longest streak of being alive was in dragon ball I'm pretty sure haha He is the fodder for DB and DBZ

Comment: @Dupree3 Thats what I originally taught aswell. Then I started hearing rumours that it was actually Goku that died most. As I did not watch all of them yet, and am not directly planning on I figured ill just ask and let facts support it ;P

Comment: Pretty sure Goku only actually dies three times tops in every version of DB combined.

Comment: Krillin has the most deaths at 5 frieza is second with four and goku only has three

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Krillin died the most number of times.** xD

Here's [the list](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_deaths_in_the_Dragon_Ball_series) (Krillin vs Goku):

**Krillin:**

Tien Shinhan Saga (Dragon Ball)

- Krillin: Killed by Tambourine. After the Tournament, he is killed by Tambourine, who was out to kill all of the greatest martial artists so that King Piccolo would go unchallenged.

Saiyan Saga

- Krillin: Killed by Frieza. Frieza lifted him into the air with his mind and blew him up, inducing Goku's first Super Saiyan transformation. He was later revived with the Namekian Dragon Balls. (Note: This was Krillin's second time dying, as he was killed by Tambourine in Dragon Ball). Ep.95

Fusion Saga

- Krillin: Turned into chocolate and eaten by Super Buu. Was later revived with the Namekian Dragon Balls.

Super 17 Saga

- Krillin: Killed by Android 17, who was brainwashed by his clone created from the depths of Hell. After Krillin tried to help 17 remember how much he hated Dr. Gero, Android 17 shot a Photon Flash through Krillin's chest.

In alternate timeline

- Future Krillin: Killed by the androids.

In second alternate timeline

- Presumably killed by Goku Black

**Goku:**

Saiyan Saga

- Goku: Killed by Piccolo, though he sacrificed himself. He held Raditz in place so he could not escape, and Piccolo shot a Special Beam Cannon through both of them. Goku was later revived with the Dragon Balls. Ep.5

Cell Games Saga

- Goku: Killed when Cell self destructs, after Goku took him to King Kai's planet. He is revived several years later when Old Kai gives him his life.

In alternate timeline

- Future Goku: Died of a heart virus.

Hit Arc

- Killed by Hit (Dragon Ball Super episode 71)

Second alternate timeline

- Killed by Goku Black when he and Zamasu switch bodies.

Comment: Please cite your sources if you copied content from another site. Please only use the backtick markdown for non-blocked content you don't want formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Not so surprisingly the answer is [Krillin](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Krillin). While this page shows he died 3 times in total in the short summery and trivia part, but I found him dying a total of 5 times including everything. [Goku](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku) seems to have died only twice.

[Total List of all character deaths can be found here.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_deaths_in_the_Dragon_Ball_series).

Comment: ohh lol.. you beat me to it. I was compiling my list from the same link. xD

Comment: btw in the same list Krillin's death toll is 5.

Comment: I did say krillin died 5 times. but your answer looks more detailed then mine. :)